# Parabolic maximum principle for non-compact manifold with boundary

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, smooth-manifolds, parabolic-pde, maximum-principle

Let $M:=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \mathbb{D}^n$, where $\mathbb{D}^n$ is the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u\colon M\times [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is solution of the following PDE
\begin{equation}\label{heat 1}
 \begin{split}
 \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}&=\Delta u\\
 u(x,0)&=u_0(x).
 \end{split}
 \end{equation}

> **Question 1:** Is there any parabolic maximum
> principle:$$ \sup_{M\times[0,\infty)} u(x,t)= \sup_{M\times\{0\}
> \cup \partial M\times[0,\infty)} u(x,t),$$ if
> $$\sup_{M\times\{0\} \cup \partial
>  M\times[0,\infty)} u(x,t)<\infty\text{?} $$

> **Question 2:** Is there a similar kind of  parabolic maximum principle for
> non-compact manifold with boundary?

Comment: These maximum principles hold if we assume that $u$ is bounded on $M \times [0, \infty[$. One needs a barrier at infinity which, in case 1, is given by $v=e^{tC}(1+|x|^2)$ (one selects $C$ so that $v_t-\Delta v \geq 0$ and applies the maximum priicniple to $u-(\|u\|_\infty)/(1+R^2) v$ in $M\cap B_R$ and let $R \to \infty$.  If $u \leq 0$ on the parabolic boundary then it is $\leq 0$ everywhere).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Would you recommend to me some references for what you wrote?

Comment: What I wrote is surely contained in the book by N. Krylov: Lectures on elliptic and parabolic problems in Holder spaces.